# Can't boot from CD/DVD ROM: HP 650 Laptop

Tags: windows-7, laptop, bootloader

I'm attempting to load Windows 7 on a HP 650 laptop. When I'm in the Boot Manager, I should be able to select the CD/DVD ROM to boot from, but that option is not available.

Here's what I do,

- Power on the computer and immediately press 'ESC' to enter the 'Startup Menu'.
- This gets me here[image]
- Then I press 'F9' to enter 'Boot Device Options'
- That gets me here [image]
- From what I find online, it should instead look like this [image]

---

I'm at a loss as to how to proceed further. Does anybody have any advice on how to boot from the CD/DVD ROM?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to press f9 and disable secure boot and set boot mode to legacy. Because Win7 cannot boot from efi. If you need I cam make a photo guide.

Comment: Brilliant! Indeed, I needed to set boot mode to legacy.

Answer (score 1):

First enter your BIOS:

"While the “Press the ESC key for Startup Menu” message is displayed in the lower-left corner of the screen, press ESC. When the Startup Menu is displayed, press F10 to enter the BIOS"

Here you can manage important settings about your system.
Enter the tab about Boot Order and enable your DVD/CD using the following hints:

"To choose a menu or a menu item, use the arrow keys.

● To choose an item in a list or to toggle a field—for example an Enable/Disable field—use either the arrow keys or f5 and f6.
● To select an item, press enter.
● To close a text box or return to the menu display, press esc.
● To display additional navigation and selection information while Setup Utility is open, press f1"

All information found on http://h20628.www2.hp.com/km-ext/kmcsdirect/emr_na-c03310281-1.pdf (The manual of your laptop)